# Find csv data in column from list of data via linq

Tags: linq

My column in my table stores a csv list of items. In C# I have a list of items and I want to do a linq query on that column returning all rows that have any of the items in the list.

Table is defined as

```
Name|Tags
```

with example data of

```
Joe | football,soccer,basketball
Mike | hockey,soccer
Steve | basketball,baseball
```

So if my C# list contains soccer and basketball I would get back Joe and Steve since they both have 1 of those in their tags list.

Note, I'm using entity framework for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bring your entity data to memory:

```
var result = players.ToList()
                    .Where(item => item.Tags.Split(',').Any(x => x.Contains("basketball") || x.Contains("baseball"));
```

Should give you 2 results.

UPDATE: providing a list of sports

```
List<string> sports = new List<string>
        {
            "baseball",
            "basketball",
            "football"
        };

var result = players.ToList()
                    .Where(item => item.Tags.Split(',').Any(sports.Contains));
```

Comment: Now imagine that instead of "soccer" we have a list of sports.

Comment: That's just 2 sports though. This would need to be a list of any number of sports.

Comment: I'm getting error "object reference not set to an instance of an object". Does the above actually run for you?

Comment: it does. do you have a tags row that has no elements?

Comment: Yeah most of them are actually NULL until filled in.

Comment: try using `item => item.Tags != null && .. `

Comment: Then just add `item.Tags != null &&`

Answer (score 0):

Say, list is your C# list. csvTable is your table.

```
var data = from csvItem in csvTable
            from tag in csvItem.Tags.split(',')
            where list.contains(tag)
            select csvItem
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying linq to entities doesn't recognize the split function.

Comment: Ok, I supposed that csvTable is a memory object.